# Yii2, GridView, bind registerJs only once

Tags: gridview, yii2

I created new GridViewExtended class using GridView. Then I need register only once pjax events. Simple example...

```
    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridViewExtended::widget([])
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
...
<?php
$this->registerJs('
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#w0").on("pjax:click", function() {
            $("#w0 .box").append($("<div class=\"overlay\"><i class=\"fa fa-refresh fa-spin\"></i></div>"));
        });

        $("#w0").on("pjax:complete", function(contents,options) {
            $("#w0 .box .overlay").remove();
        });

        $("#w0 .box .overlay").remove();
    });'
);
?>
```

So i want this js was registered in GridViewExtended class. If I redefine GridViewExtended::run() and register it there, this js applies on each call (in frontent).

Mean that on fist click (for example pagination) it will be called once, on second twice... And this brokes whole logic.

Ofcourse it works if I register it on view, but I want register it in GridViewExtended.

Please help.

Comment: And what's the point? all in tags pjax will be redifene\rebind on each call... I need somehow register it outside but in gridview model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect ajax calls and not register the JS if it is an ajax call.

```
if(!Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    add your JS code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by rendering content on ajax with $this->renderAjax() method in action. As I understood it uses current (already loaded in front) scripts to redefine\rebind actions and not firing then "again" .